# How to custom object between two storyboard in one project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have two storyboard in my project. I am usually can navigate from one View of storyboard to another View of another storyboard?

I am writing code as below

```
 UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Details" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];

    // Get button tag number (or do whatever you need to do here, based on your object
    NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

    vc.modalTransitionStyle =UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Now, I have three buttons, and tag on them, How can I pass Custom Object, kept in array to next controller of another storyboard ("DETAIL").

Thanks

Comment: There are thousands of questions and answers about passing data between controllers on SO, you should check them out. The fact that the two controllers are in different storyboards is irrelevant. All you need to pass the data is a reference to that next controller (which you have, vc).

Comment: I know, but this is exception case , means between two different storboards, how can I do so?

Comment: As I said, that's irrelevant. Passing data is a two step process. One, get a reference to the controller you're passing to (you have that with vc), and two, set the value of property you've created in the controller you're passing to, equal to something in the current controller that you want to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard2" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard2initialviewcontroller"] animated:NO];
```

EDIT :

Maybe like this, not sure it will help but i ll try :)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        MyOtherViewController *destination = (MyOtherViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.someProperty = self.someOtherProperty;
    }
}
```

and

```
UIStoryboard *secondStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"secondStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
MyOtherViewController *myViewController = (MyOtherViewController *)[secondStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myOtherViewController"];

myViewController.someProperty = self.someOtherProperty;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry, You are not reading my question properly dear. Its wrong what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the custom object like below

```
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Details" bundle:nil];
 HomeViewController *homeVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];

 // here I am passing string to the another controller (i.e HomeViewController), you can pass any object that you want

 homeVC.info = @"This is test string";
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeVC animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps you